# access first argument of call() method of the ES6 arrow function

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Is there any way to access the first argument of the call() method of the ES6 arrow function?

```
var obj = {
  getFn: function() { return () => {
      //how to access bar here
      return this.what;
    }
  },
  any: 1
}


var foo = obj.getFn();
var bar = {
  any: 2
};

foo.call(bar);
```

Comment: The code doesn't make a lot sense: The object literal syntax is incorrect. I assume you mean `getFn: () =>`. But `getFn` doesn't return a function, unless `this.what` is a function of course. But if that's the case, then you will never access `bar` inside the function anyway, since `foo.call(bar)` will call what `this.what` refers to, not `obj.getFn`.

Comment: You'r right. There was a mistake. getFn returns new arrow function. So, bar argument in foo.call(bar) just disappears?

Comment: Ok. Doesn't change anything either way.

Comment: So the answer is "the first argument of foo.call(bar) just disappears"? Am I right?

Comment: Did you mean `this.any` instead of `this.what`?

Comment: No. I understand that I can't change context with .call(). But I didn't understand the destiny of the first argument of the .call() method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you are asking how to access the `this` value passed via `.call`, the answer is: *you can't*.

Since arrow functions don't have their own `this`, there is nothing that `.call` could set the value to. If you want a function to have its own `this` value, don't use an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by Felix, arrow functions does not have own this value, so `.call` and `.apply` methods can't change the `this` of arrow function.

If you want to get access to the `bar` inside your arrow function, you can pass it via argument.

```
var obj = {
  getFn: function() { 
    return (bar) => {
      console.log(bar);
      return this.what;
    }
  },
  any: 1
};

var foo = obj.getFn();
var bar = {
  any: 2
};

foo(bar); // prints bar into console
```